# Pandas Apply Function Slow Speed

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a dataframe (approx 1 - 3 M records) that I am running an apply() function on. It's taking a considerable amount of time. I've read a few places that I should not be using apply(), however I am unsure how to accomplish the same task with out it.

The dataframe is transactional sales data. I am grouping by "APN", then re-creating a fresh pd.Series

```
def f(x):
    d = {}
    d['fips_2'] = x["fips"].values[0]
    d['apn_2'] = x["apn"].values[0]
    d['most_recent_sale'] = x["recording_date"].nlargest(1).iloc[-1]
    d['second_most_recent_sale'] = x["recording_date"].nlargest(2).iloc[-1]
    d['third_most_recent_sale'] = x["recording_date"].nlargest(3).iloc[-1]
    d['most_recent_price'] = x.loc[x["recording_date"] == d["most_recent_sale"], "price"].values[0]
    d['second_most_recent_price'] = x.loc[x["recording_date"] == d["second_most_recent_sale"], "price"].values[0]
    d['third_most_recent_price'] = x.loc[x["recording_date"] == d["third_most_recent_sale"], "price"].values[0]
    d['second_grantor'] = x.loc[x["recording_date"] == d["most_recent_sale"], "seller"].values[0]
    d['prior_grantor'] = x.loc[x["recording_date"] == d["second_most_recent_sale"], "seller"].values[0]
    d['type'] = x["type"].values[0]

    print(x["apn"].values[0])

    return pd.Series(d, index=['apn_2', 'most_recent_sale', 'second_most_recent_sale', 'most_recent_price', 'second_most_recent_price', 'second_grantor', 'type'])

df_grouped = year_past_df.groupby("apn").apply(f)
```

Is there a better way to accomplish the same task but with greater speed?

Comment: It's one dataframe. year_past_df represents transactions within the past year. I then groupby particular items "apn" and need to see for each "apn" for example what is the most recent sale, second most recent sales price, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One improvement could be to remove the several `nlargest` calls and do a sorting once at the beginning. I do not know all the columns as an example dataset is missing but something like this might work:

```
def f(x):
    x = x.sort_values("recording_date")
    d = {}
    d['fips_2'] = x["fips"].values[0]
    d['apn_2'] = x["apn"].values[0]
    d['most_recent_sale'] = x.sale.iloc[-1]
    d['second_most_recent_sale'] = x.sale.iloc(-2)
    d['third_most_recent_sale'] = x.sale.iloc(-2)
    d['most_recent_price'] = x.price.iloc(-1)
    d['second_most_recent_price'] = x.price.iloc(-2)
    d['third_most_recent_price'] = x.price.iloc(-3)
    d['second_grantor'] = x.seller.iloc(-1)
    d['prior_grantor'] = x.seller.iloc(-2)
    d['type'] = x["type"].values[0]
    return pd.Series(d, index=['apn_2', 'most_recent_sale', 'second_most_recent_sale', 'most_recent_price', 'second_most_recent_price', 'second_grantor', 'type'])

df_grouped = year_past_df.groupby("apn").apply(f)
```

Another option would be to do the sorting at the beginning over the whole dataset and then use the `agg` function similar to this:

```
agg_dir = {
    'fips': 'first',
    'sale': ['last', lambda x: x.iloc[-2], lambda x: x.iloc[-3]],
    'price': ['last', lambda x: x.iloc[-2], lambda x: x.iloc[-3]],
    'seller': ['last', lambda x: x.iloc[-2]],
    'type': 'first'
}
df_grouped = year_past_df.sort_values("recording_date").groupby("apn").agg(agg_dir)
df_grouped.columns = ['fips_2', 'most_recent_sale', 'second_most_recent_sale', 
                      'third_most_recent_sale', 'most_recent_price', 'second_most_recent_price', 
                      'third_most_recent_price', 'second_grantor', 'prior_grantor', 'type']
```